# How to enable and use '_' in MeanJS?

Tags: javascript, lodash, meanjs

I'm trying to use lodash from within a mongoose model on the server, `_.pluck(...)`, and I'm getting "ReferenceError: _ is not defined".

From what I read, lodash is included in [MeanJS](http://meanjs.org/docs.html). Is there something special I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you need to require it just like any other module. I [searched for "lodash" in the MEAN.JS source](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=lodash) and this came up several times:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

It's included into MEAN.JS project by default. Generate sample application and see the usage examples.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Article = mongoose.model('Article'),
    _ = require('lodash');`
```